# CDI WELD Beans.xml in META-INF from jar in lib blocking the one in WEB-INF of project

Tags: java, cdi, weld

Depending on where I place my beans.xml's, in my project CDI is either working for @Named annotated classes found in lib jars OR for @Alternative annotated classes found in the main project. I can't figure out where to place them to get both to work.

Upon building I have a core.jar that has some @Default annotated classes and some @Named annotated classes.

The core.jar is located in the web-inf/lib in my project.

In that project, depending on environment build, I use some @Alternative annotated classes which are specified in the beans.xml of the web project (in WEB-INF)

So, I have 2 beans.xml

1 in the META-INF of a core.jar that is build and placed in the project lib AND
1 in the WEB-INF of the war project that gets deployed (with alternatives specified)

With both beans.xml files at those locations, the beanhandler does not find the alternatives specified in the beans.xml (the one in the web-inf of the war)

When I remove the beans.xml from the META-INF from the jar dependency and redeploy, the alternatives are working fine (strangely) but then the @Named annotated classes are no longer found...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
From CDI 1.1 onwards the alternative can be enabled for the whole
 application using @Priority annotation.
```

As described in [alternatives](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#alternatives) then you would not need to depend on beans.xml as activation point for the alternatives.